# Is there a way to specify function type with an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Im using express and i know you can do the following to set teh type of the reques handler.

```
router.get("/", <RequestHandler> function (req, res, next) {
  //Manage request here
});
```

Is there a way to do the same with arrow functions? I know I can just specify the type of each param but thats a bit verbose I think.

I know this works

```
router.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  //Manage request here
});
```

But could something like this work?

```
router.get("/", <RequestHandler>(req, res, next) => {
  //Manage request here
});
```

I get the following error for every parameter.

> Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 2):

With an arrow function, you must surround the whole function expression in parentheses to avoid syntactical issues.

```
router.get("/", <RequestHandler>((req, res, next) => {
  //Manage request here
}));
```

Another option with `as`

```
router.get(
  "/",
  ((req, res, next) => {
  //Manage request here
  }) as RequestHandler
)
```

Another option, declare the callback as a standalone variable beforehand, avoiding type assertions entirely

```
const callback: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  //Manage request here
} as RequestHandler;

router.get("/", RequestHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Typescript 4.9+, you could make use of the `satisfies` keyword:

```
interface AddFunc {
    (a: number, b: number): number;
}

const add = ((a, b) => {
    return a + b
}) satisfies AddFunc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this: `<RequestHandler<{type1; type2; type3}>>`
Or you can create a separate interface